# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't load after upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, user-management

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 and now it keep loading and never boots.

sometimes the login page appears and after entering the correct password the page simply splashes and nothing happens. I'm also not able to go on a guest session.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering a weird bug like this. At the login screen hit `ctrl + alt + f2` and make sure you can log in there. if you can, you should link `/sbin/init` and `/sbin/initctl` to `/bin/init` and `/bin/initctl` respectively. I just ran `ln -s /sbin/init /bin/init` and  the same for `initctl` and it seemed to clean the problem right up.

Comment: well when I run some of the commands I get "ln: failed to create symbolic link '/bin/initctl' : File exists"

Comment: @wadie interesting. Can you please paste the contents of the file `~/.xsession-errors` ?